# Checking how many weekends are within date range

Tags: php, laravel, date, range, weekend

How do I check in Laravel how many Saturdays or Sundays are in given date range between `$from` and `$to`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with plain PHP like this:

```php
$start = new DateTime('2016-07-07');
$end = new DateTime('2016-07-27');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);

$saturdays = 0;
foreach($daterange as $date){
    $days = $date->format('D');
    if ($days == 'Sat') {
        $saturdays++;
    }
}

echo $saturdays;
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use day numbers to avoid localization issues 
`$days = $date->format('N');` and `if ($days == 6)` for Saturday

Comment: It is, this is just example to understand it better

Comment: Initially i have the carbon method for laravel.. but the solution here are better.Thanks guys! Ervald & Jakob.. combined both of ur method gets a better result.

Comment: @shahru I am glad it works for you. Just a note because I see you are new at SO. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.